# Connect disconnected components wherever no more than n pixels is required to do so

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, scikit-image

I'm wondering if there's a library implementation of this.

In OpenCV we have the concept of finding connected components with either 4-way or 8-way connectivity. I'd like to be able to do so, then bridge the gap between disconnected components as long as flipping only 1 pixel would be required to do so. See the images below for examples

Two 4-way connected components where we can bridge the gap to make them into one 4-way connected component. So I could use a function like `connect4way(max_bridge_size=1)` to do so

[image]

Two 4-way connected components where we can bridge the gap to make them into one 8-way connected components. Using `connect4way(max_bridge_size=1)` would fail, but I could use `connect8way(max_bridge_size=1)` to achieve this.
[image]

I do realise that there are often cases in which there's not a deterministic way to do what I ask, especially for the case of `max_bridge_size > 1`. Nevertheless, I ask.

Comment: I think you want a *"morphological closing"* operation.

Comment: I think you're (mostly) right :) I haven't taken the time to examine all edge cases, but it seems like there's at least one way that this would flip more pixels than I intend it to.

Comment: Would you care to share a representative image along with a second, marked-up version highlighting the acceptable/expected bridging pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been having a think about this and think I am close, but I am not certain exactly what you want and don't have a representative image from you yet. You, or someone else, may be able to finish it off.

The basic idea is to label all the pixels of each blob of white with a unique number. Then pass over the image looking at 3x3 squares and reporting any pixel in which there is more than one unique neighbour - i.e. any pixel that is beside 2 differently labeled blobs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label, generate_binary_structure, generic_filter

def bridger(P):
    """
    We receive P[0]..P[8] with the pixels in the 3x3 surrounding window.
    We want to identify pixels with two different neighbouring labels plus background.
    Maybe we want to check the centre pixel P[4] is black?
    """
    neighbours = len(np.unique(P)) - 1
    if neighbours > 1:
        return 255
    return 0
    
   
# Load input image
im = cv2.imread('start.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Threshold to force everything to pure black or white 
_, bw = cv2.threshold(im,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-bw.png', bw)

# The default SE (structuring element) is for 4-connectedness, i.e. only pixels North, South, East and West of another are considered connected.
# We want 8-connected, i.e. N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW, so we need a corresponding SE
SE = generate_binary_structure(2,2)   

# Now run a labelling, or "Connected Components Analysis"
# Each "blob" of connected pixels matching our seed will get assigned a unique number in the new image called "labeled"
labeled, nObjects = label(bw, structure=SE)
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-labels.png', labeled)
print(f'Objects found: {nObjects}')

# Look for bridging pixels in each 3x3 neighbourhood
result = generic_filter(labeled, bridger, (3,3))

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

Start Image:

[image]

Labeled Image:

[image]

Result Image - located pixels in cyan:

[image]

Comment: I think this does it. Thank you!

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project! Btw, I think you can do *"Connected Components"* with **OpenCV** too - I just happen to have used `scipy` version before and had some code lying around.

Comment: Yes I normally do it with OpenCV