# How can I connect close pixels in an Image?

Tags: python, image-processing, pixel, captcha

I'm trying to create a program that the given input is an image, example:
[image]

and it would detect close pixels and connect them like this:

[image]

I have already tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66106373/16469230
but couldn't get it to work...
I also tried blurring it, but the gaps are just too big.
If you got any idea on how to solve this problem, I would like to hear it!
Thanks!

Comment: A morphological closing should close those gaps just fine. You need to find the right size kernel, that’s all.

Comment: @Chris How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What if there is a pixels that is close each other but we dont want to connect them, how program can understand what part of close pixels need to be connected.

This is so hard to do, first of all you have to make programm that can detect if there is a numbers or letters, after that try to make that numbers or letters connecting closest pixels.

I think this is the only way to make programm like that

Comment: I will set a var that has the max distance of pixels to connect... and the letters don't come closer, I just need a program that gets an image and a var with max distance and connects the pixels that are within that distance